# How could Spring find his classes in a project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Probably this would be a trivial and nonsense question but, being a Spring neophyte, I've always asked to myself "How Spring can use classes in a project which extends his classes?"

For example the `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`:

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer 
{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

    }

}
```

My `Initializer` class it's declared in a hand-built package with a non special name so I wonder: How could Spring find and instantiates my `Initializer` class? Does it make any sort of "package scan" of my project trying to get all classes which extends his own, or something?

Comment: WebApplicationInitializer initializes on startup of your application and registers the servlet based on the "/" mapping in the web.xml. So all the *servletInitializers implements WebApplicationInitializer.

For future reference : http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

Comment: Added a better explanation: I meant in which way Spring instantiates my Initializer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet container scans the classes of the webapp at deployment time. That what allows it to auto-register classes annotated with @WebServlet as servlets, classes annotated as @WebFilter as servlet filters, etc.

It also allows if to find the classes implementing [javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html), and to call their onStartup() method, which allows the initializer to register servlets and filters dynamically. The Spring class SpringServletContainerInitializer is such a class, which in turn delegates to your own Initializer.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!